# Updated approach to Reauthenticate a user

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been looking in the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users?authuser=0) and found the method to reauthenticate a user shown below.

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
var credential: AuthCredential

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials

user?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
  if let error = error {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
    // User re-authenticated.
  }
}
```

I get an error and a warning though from the compiler as follows:

Error:

> Variable 'credential' used before being initialized

Warning:

> 'reauthenticate(with:completion:)' is deprecated: Please use
>   reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential:completion: for
>   Objective-C or
>   reauthenticateAndRetrieveData(WithCredential:completion:) for Swift
>   instead.

Has anyone an example of an updated method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
var credential: AuthCredential
user?.reauthenticateAndRetrieveData(with: credential, completion: {(authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                // An error happened.
            }else{
                // User re-authenticated.
            }
        })
```

You are getting error because you haven't initialize **credential**
You have to initialize [AuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthCredential) first

These credential can vary from

> [EmailAuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/EmailAuthCredential.htm)
>
> [FacebookAuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FacebookAuthCredential.html)
>
> [GithubAuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/GithubAuthCredential.html)
>
> [GoogleAuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/GoogleAuthCredential.html)
>
> [PhoneAuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthCredential.html)
>
> [PlayGamesAuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PlayGamesAuthCredential.html)
>
> [TwitterAuthCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/TwitterAuthCredential.html)

Initiziale the variable according to your authentication method e.g.
if you have chosen email you can use like

```
var credential: AuthCredential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: "email", password: "pass")
```

Comment: Thanks. In the example of initializing you gave, are “email” and “pass” placeholders? What do they do?

Comment: These credentials are used to reauthenticate the users. Can you please tell me how did you authenticate the user first time

Comment: Hmm.. I think what you mean is that I need to work on my workflow.  When I create a user using `Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailAddress, password: userPassword)`, I can use textfields to provide the parameters.  For reauthentication to work, do I need to re-request the password in app again?  That isn't clear from the Firebase documentation.  Is there also a notification sent to the user's email box informing them that their account has been signed into again?  Do they have to click on a link in the mail?

Comment: The user is already created. We are just trying for re authentication. Like a normal login. So they shouldn't be getting verify email.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd expected some sort of email to authenticate the account but indeed it is just a question of the user logging in again.